# Model or equation for deciding who gets to play

Tags: distributions, estimation

I am a team manager for an amateur sports team. We play 2 games a week and use a game roster of 40 people. However, our team roster includes around 55-60 people and there is competition for spots for every game. I would like to have a fair and not subjective system of rotating who gets to participate in games as previous years there is constant discussion about why X got to play instead of Y. We play around 100 games a year

Some players sign up for every game and others sign up for only 50 or 75%. I would like a system where everyone misses the same proportion of games they sign up for (i.e. a game they dont sign up for doesnt penalize them in the future). I thought about tracking attendance and just using the ratio of games played in/signed for as a value and then inviting those with lowest value to every game. However I run into a problem where for example player A (played in/sign up for) 15/20=.75 and player B 60/80=.75 but a further missed games equals 15/21=.71 and 60/81=.74, meaning player A would then be invited to more games despite having missed fewer games they signed for compared to player B. Essentially the games he is forced to miss are worth much more compared to someone who has signed for more games.

Is there any good way to deal with statisically? Would normalizing values help? Can I modify my idea in any good way or any other ideas how to solve this.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: So for each person and game, you track whether the person signed up to play, and then whether they actually showed up on game day. Why do you want to preferentially invite the no-shows, who are the people with the lowest ratio of showing up to signing up? Seems like you're encouraging the wrong thing - if I want to be invited to the next game, I should sign up for every game and never show up. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You are correct, to counter this we have had a penalty for signing up and not actually being available to play. This is so we dont have to show up shorthanded. So what I do is that from everyone who has signed up I pick the final 40 man game day roster; and if it turns out they cant actually attend they get the penalty. But since we are often overbooked there is no penatly if you actually dont sign up for a game because you know you cant make it